# Gnuplot pm3d at sb

Tags: gnuplot

This is my second question today, I thought about editing the other one with this info but the problems doesn't seem to be related... So, with [this data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13wStlZ7XCPjr0N0W0xGGmhUTuxEtQIhs/view), and using this code:

```
set terminal qt
s=101
set size square
set palette rgb 34,35,36;
set zrange[-1.8e-5:1.8e-5]
set pm3d at sb
set autoscale fix
do for [i=0:0]{
splot 'itp.txt' u 1:2:3 every:::(i*s)::(s+i*s) notitle w pm3d
}
```

I get [this black image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O3pD.png). This is clearly not working properly... but if I slide my finger through my notebook's touchpad while in the qt's output interactive window, [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2F2X.png) pops up, which is what I wanted. It seems to work everywhere, except when the graph fit the "canvas". [Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSdJD.png) & [example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABl48.png). I'm not even sure what sliding my fingers through the touchpad while on qt's output window does, but it seems to be fixing something. So what should I do? Thank you in advance!

*qt is the qt terminal in gnuplot

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the two figures you posted, it seems that the effect has to do with a changing `xrange`. I copied your datafile and script, and adding:

```
set xrange[-200:300]
```

did the trick for me. Also, you may consider fixing (if at all possible) your color bar range, by adding:

```
set cbrange[xx:xx]
```

with your data, I tried:

```
set cbrange[0:1.8e-8]
```

and the result looks completely different. Hope this helps.